# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in JComboBox App

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.* ;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
private JComboBox box ;

private JLabel picture ;

private static String[] filename={"Phone.png","Music.png"};

private Icon[] pics={new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0]))};

    public GUI(){
        super("JComboBox");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        box=new JComboBox (filename);

        box.addItemListener(
            new ItemListener(){
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
                    if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                        picture.setIcon(pics[box.getSelectedIndex()]);
                }
            }
            );

        add(box);
        picture=new JLabel(pics[0]);
        add(picture);
    }
}
```

When I try to check `music.png` it gives me this error

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>         at GUI$1.itemStateChanged(GUI.java:20)
>         at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireItemStateChanged(JComboBox.java:1222)
>         at javax.swing.JComboBox.selectedItemChanged(JComboBox.java:1279)
>         at javax.swing.JComboBox.contentsChanged(JComboBox.java:1326)
>         ...
> ```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, rather than a partial screeshot.

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Always copy/paste error or exception output (as opposed to a link to a screenshot showing your IDE & part of the stack trace). 3) See also [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/418556)

Comment: @dimo414


to trace the error

http://pastebin.com/b5U1gN5x

Comment: am sorry this first post in stackoverflow 

i will post full stack trace in the next time 

thanks for edit :)

Comment: *"am sorry"* No need to be sorry at all. :) *"i will post full stack trace in the next time"* ..because that is way better.  +1.  And welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson 

thanks brother :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start with the fact that you've specified two file names, but only loaded one image

```
private static String[] filename = {"Phone.png", "Music.png"};
private Icon[] pics = {new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0]))};
```

Try loading both images...

```
private Icon[] pics = {
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[0])),
    new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(filename[1]))
};
```